# How to access a TGraph with uproot?

Tags: uproot

I'm trying to access a ROOT TGraph with uproot. In the uproot tutorial (https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot#histograms-tprofiles-tgraphs-and-others) TGraphs are mentioned, but no where is written how to load them to python. Could somebody show me a code sniplet of how to do that? 
Thank you already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example given for a histogram, it's `tfile["tgraph_name"]`, where `tfile` is the open file object and `"tgraph_name"` is the name of the `TGraph`. The object this returns has all of the *data* that a `TGraph` contains, but only has the methods [defined here](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot-methods/blob/master/uproot_methods/classes/TGraph.py). (uproot-methods is a separate package so that you can freely add methods that you feel are missing.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now! :-)